# Can I XMLHTTPRequest(); plain HTML (without XML)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a google chrome extension and I need to circumvent the same origin policy:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "my url", true);
```

However, "my url" is the URL of an HTML page (more specifically a JavaScript template) and I am getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" from my console.

How do I accept this XML using the google chrome extension xhr method of GET (I can't use .ajax due to the same origin policy and calling it JSONP does not allow the HTML to parse)?

Comment: More details are needed. what is the response of `my url`? Where's the rest of your function?

Comment: Yes, even though XMLHttpRequest is an AJAX funtion, which stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, HTML is a perfectly ok too.

Comment: The response is " ". It's not part of a function yet, I'm just trying to get it to work. 
If HTML is valid, why is it getting tripped up by the first "<"?

Comment: @user995469: surely it's not XMLHttpRequest who is getting tripped, but some code you use later.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use jsonp to get the data. To parse it , not sure how you are planning to parse html but it will be easier if that html too is properly formatted, you can create a proxy that would return a well formatted html or xml. In the proxy you can use tidyhtml which can take badly formatted html and output a xml or xhtml formatted data of the html. Otherwise you would be doing lot of string manipulation. Either way, you should be getting your data by jsonp. You can load it into some html element of web page and manipulate it by jquery.
problem with loading html using jsonp is that you would need to escape few html characters before being able to pass it through a callback function.